# Querying an elasticsearch index for data that isn't 1:1 with the document

Tags: elasticsearch

If I start with normalised data, something like:

```
Book 
|->belongs to Author
|->belongs to Genre
```

And I denormalise this in my ES index, I might arrive at something with rows like:

```
book1 author1 genre1
book2 author1 genre2
book3 author2 genre1
book4 author3 genre1
```

This index seems like it would naturally answer queries about `book`, because each document is 1:1 with `book`.

But what if I want to answer queries about `author` or `genre` with no reference to `book`? Say to expose a UI with a list of `author` filterable by `author name` and `genre`. Or a list of `genre` with no reference to `book` or `author`?

I could easily create an index each for `author`, `book`, and `genre`, but that either turns my index into a mirror of my normalised relational data (which defeats the purpose of fast search in a denormalised index) or I have to update 3 indexes any time an author changes.

If I choose to simplify indexing in this way, will I create an unsustainable problem for myself when querying?

Aggregates are a thing I've heard of for generating documents grouped by some common field. Is that something I can use here?

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on how complex your data set is. if you have tons of fields you want to normalize you can use [Terms Lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup) and separate `Author` and `Book` in separate indices and link them using an `id`.

However, if you data set is not too huge, then you can do as simple as below example :

You can search on either author or the book and it will return all documents that match the query

```
PUT t1

POST t1/_doc/1
{
  "book": "book1",
  "author": "author1"
}

POST t1/_doc/2
{
  "book": "book2",
  "author": "author1"
}

POST t1/_doc/3
{
  "book": "book3",
  "author": "author2"
}

POST t1/_doc/4
{
  "book": "book4",
  "author": "author3"
}
```

QUERY 1 - book lookup - returns book 1

```
 POST t1/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "book": [
            "book1"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    #Response
    {
      "took" : 0,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 1,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "t1",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "book" : "book1",
              "author" : "author1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

QUERY 2 - author lookup - returns book1 and book2

```
POST t1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "author": [
        "author1"
      ]
    }
  }
}

#Author Response
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "t1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "book" : "book1",
          "author" : "author1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "t1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "book" : "book2",
          "author" : "author1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel the second option is on the right track. What if I want to manage authors with a UI that only cares about authors, and not books? i.e. start with a list of all authors and narrow it down by the `author name` and other fields on the index that can be understood independent of book (`author dob`, `genre` etc). And say I also want a another UI for managing only `genre` (again, no book fields)? Is it weird to handle all those independent queries from a single index?